# How to run an action / script after files all files are copied to target install dir?

Tags: installshield

Due to the buggy nature of InstallShield, it is incorrectly modifying my app.config files replacing `<clear />` with `<clear></clear>`

After my app.config file is copied to install path, I want to run a custom action that can scan for all config files and do a standard find and replace.

I don't need code for the find and replace, what I want to know is how / where to put this custom action using Installshield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be creating a [deferred execution custom action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368268(v=vs.85).aspx) and place it near the end of the execution sequence. This will guarantee it would run after the files have been installed.

In the 'Custom Actions and Sequences', Create a new custom action of the appropriate type (depending on your implementation of this replacement action). Set it's In-Script Execution to 'Deferred' and in the Sequence section have add it to the Install Exec Sequence, After ScheduleReboot.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to modify config/ini files after deployment of files is the option of `INI File Changes` or `Text File Changes` under the System Configuration tab. You can mention the config file location and the replacement changes that you want to perform. Please refer this [link](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/TextFileChanges-SrchRplc.htm).